# How to create an excel formula from cells that has int and str values?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007, vba

I am currently a scheduler in the restaurant I'm working. My manager has asked me if there's a way to generate a formula of the total time our workers work in a week.
I can get the sum of two cells if there are two different cells, as shown in the photo, but what formula or is there a formula where you can get the sum of two numbers from one cell? And they contain letters as well. 10:30am-04:30pm is = how many hours(formula).

[See photo below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEnys.jpg)

Comment: As a rule, each cell needs to contain a single time value. If you start entering strings like "10:00-12:00" in one cell, then Excel will not recognise it as a time value and will simply store it as a string - upon which you won't be able to perform calculations (unless you construct a complicated nest of formulæ).
Can you redesign your spreadsheet to account for single time values in each cell?

Comment: I can't since we not only post it online but also print it out to post in our office board. But your recommendation is helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have dates in column `A`, you can use this formula in Column `B` to get time difference value in `HH:MM` output.

```
=TEXT((TRIM(MID(A1,FIND("-",A1,1)+1,10))-(LEFT(A1,FIND("-",A1,1)-3))),"hh:mm")
```

[image]

Comment: This formula works in some cases, but not all.  Instead of -3 in the left function, -1 would preserve the am/pm, which would reduce some errors.  (i.e. if cell A1 was "1:30 pm-4:30 pm", your formula would return 15 hours).  If anyone works a shift that goes past midnight, this would also fail.  This would require an if statement to get past.

Comment: Yes you are right. Thanks for adding this comment!

Comment: cool! So just change -3 to -1, yeah?

Comment: Yes, and please vote accepted if this solves your request.